# Cutting a curved pipe in half along its length, turning it into a non enclosed water slide

Tags: modeling, path

So I have this curved pipe made out of a path + bevel + turned curve into mesh.

[image]

I need to remove its top part, making at look like an open water slide, something like this:

[image]

Comment: hello, so what about selecting the edge loops and deleting them?

Comment: Instead of using round bevel for the curve, you could try a bevel object. Then add a solidify modifier

Comment: @moonboots that works, but the slide's concave portion doesnt always point up, sometimes it will point down because the curve is probably twisted, how to make the curve points be oriented in a way that this doesn't happen?

Comment: You can select individual points and adjust their twist in the 3D Viewport properties panel (not to be confused with the Properties editor).

Comment: I think there’s also a setting in the curve data to make it always face in one direction. Check “twist method.”

Comment: @TheLabCat the twist method thing worked

Answer (score 2):

If you want, at least, to adjust the basic shape before committing yourself to  conversion to a mesh, you can use the 'Half' setting in the Shape panel of your curve and give it a native Round bevel in its Geometry panel...

[image]

You will need to adjust the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> Tilt of all the control-points of the spline to -90°, and set the Twist Method to Z-Up, to have the cup face upward, throughout the curve.

[image]

Here, shown with additional *Solidify*, *Bevel*, and *Subdiv*. modifiers