# Tube Slide Rotation

Tags: modeling

I am making a waterslide with a spiral on it. To make this, I have used a Nurbs Curve and applied an Array and Curve modifier to a small section of my slide which made it go all the way down the spiral. But my problem is that the side of the slide is rotated from being on the side at the top to being near the top at the bottom. I am trying to keep it all at the same level staying on the side and I can't figure out a way to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate.. (although, I know, they're sometimes hard to find)
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/281197/35559

Comment: +1 RobinBetts ... YoDub - you should mainly care a **Tilt** rotation of each control point of your Curve object (used in modifier).

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much you two, I doubt I would have figured it out.